# How do I add "uses-permissions" tags to AndroidManifest.xml for a Cordova project?

Tags: android, cordova

Some `<uses-permission>` entries are added automatically to AndroidManifest.xml, based on cordova plugins that you add.  However, I need the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permission, which isn't added automatically.

I can add that directly to AndroidManifest.xml, but it will get overwritten the next time I run `cordova build`, and I don't want to have to keep re-adding it...

I'm sure there's a "Cordova" way of specifying permissions (in config.xml, or elsewhere), but I'm not seeing it in [their documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File) anywhere...

So, what is the "Cordova way" of specifying user permissions?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As I know AndroidManifest.xml will not be generated every time when you run `cordova build`. When you add/remove a plugin it will be modified accordingly. But if you add your own permissions it will not be removed(Unless there is a conflict).

Since the permissions are Android (platform) specific, in your case you have to add it into the **AndroidManifest.xml** file only.

Even in plugin.xml of any plugin they add permission as shown :

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

Which says add uses-permission line to AndroidManifest.xml file at the installation time of plugin. But you cant mention this in config.xml file.

Also don't forget to put this attribute in the root widget element present in the **config.xml** file,located in the root folder of the app, as @hiddentao said in a comment.

**config.xml**

```
<widget
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  ...>
```

Comment: I didn't realize that some manual modifications to AndroidManifest.xml remain after a build (as most manual changes get stomped).  I thought I had tested manually adding a "uses-permission" tag, but I guess not...  I guess I should test a little better before posting questions :)

Comment: To get this working I also had to add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to the root `widget` tag in my config.xml

Comment: I'm relatively new to the hybrid dev scene, but aren't the `config-file` and `uses-permission` elements provided by the `cordova-custom-config` plugin? I couldn't get this to work until I added that plugin (as mentioned in Dorad's answer) and followed it's setup, which includes the `xmlns:android` definition that hiddentai mentions in the comment above... To me the selected answer here seems incomplete. :/

Comment: Without the @hiddentao `widget` addition above, you get an unbound prefix error.

Comment: @hiddentao informed to put the attribute in the config.xml present in the root folder of the app, not the plugin.xml. Please check my edit.

Comment: Using this approach I end up with message `Conflict found, edit-config changes from config.xml will overwrite plugin.xml changes` after `cordova prepare` command. Also the AndroidManifest is missing some permissions required by plugins.

Comment: For anyone looking for the `config-file` docs: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/plugin_ref/spec.html#config-file

Answer (score 30):

Cordova (version 8) has [built in functionality for this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config).

I was able to add the required 'uses-permission' line to `AndroidManifest.xml` using the following in `config.xml`:

```
<platform name="android">
    ...
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/uses-permission" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    </edit-config>
    ...
</platform>
```

Comment: if you have tried other methods for amending your config you can reset it by <br/>`cordova platform remove android <br/>cordova platform add android`

Comment: This setting will **replace** a previous configuration. Or, add a new attribute. In this case, replace the first `uses-permission` that there is.

Answer (score 15):

One can add this [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config) ([Git](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config)).
It makes you capable of defining platform-specific configurations (permissions too) under config.xml file in the following way:

```
<platform name="android">
    <custom-config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
         <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />-->
    </custom-config-file>
</platform>
```

Also don't forget to put this attribute in the root widget element as @hiddentao said in a comment.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, though <config-file> should be <custom-config-file> as per the plugin doc

Comment: Thanks @Gagan. You are right, that was changed in the fifth release of the plugin. I am now editing my post.

Answer (score 4):

Manually add under config-file tag

```
 <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</config-file>
```

Comment: Works for me with cordova 8.0.0

Comment: You need to add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to the root `widget` tag in config.xml.

Comment: App crash after adding <config-file> tag