# uses-permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in ionic3

Tags: android, angular, cordova, typescript, ionic3

I am just stuck.
**I wanted to Download MP3 file to my app.**
I am able to download the **same in browser** while working on it,
As we know, there we need to provide `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. 
To do so what I did is as below-

1. Opened `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml`
2. added

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
   But its not working for me.
   Let me share my Machine Setup-

   cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

   ```
   @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
   ```

   global packages:

   ```
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
   ```

   local packages:

   ```
   @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
   Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
   ```

   I try for this 
   https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/

Also try  https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config-example/blob/master/config.xml

There is a way for cordova and another way to provide permissions 
[How do I add "uses-permissions" tags to AndroidManifest.xml for a Cordova project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042088/how-do-i-add-uses-permissions-tags-to-androidmanifest-xml-for-a-cordova-projec) 
I am unable to write it.

Help me plz...

Comment: what's android version?

Comment: Its 5.1, and related, not marshmallow, I know there is some issue with marshmallow.

Answer (score 0):

open your ts file and write this code

```
checkPermissions(){
        this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions(
           [
             this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA,  
             this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.GET_ACCOUNTS, 
             this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
             this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
           ]
        );
    }
```

this resolved my problem.