# Ionic - Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"

Tags: android, ionic-framework, opentok

Tring to use opentok in an ionic app and i get this error in log when I try to publish a video

> Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist" Access
>   denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist2"

i hev tried to add these permissions in the app manifist

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one reason was not having permission to record audio as well

Answer (score 1):

First I'd like to declare that i'm not ionic developer but from my experience as android developer you can try to add camera permission or prevent the app from using the camera 
see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30043686/7872110) to know how to add permissions and add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

else if you want to prevent app from using camera add this

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

note in ionice 4

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge">
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
</edit-config>
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I have these permissions in the app manifist but still have the issue

Comment: if you are authorized you can upload it to github so i can run it and reproduce the problem