# cordova android avd access apache server xampp config.xml permission

Tags: android, cordova, permissions, xampp, android-virtual-device

I installed XAMPP for windows:

https://www.apachefriends.org/de/download.html

Then I set up an application for android:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-cordova

Everything works fine. I can fetch the data from my webserver:

[image: Data Webserver]

Then I fetch the data with Axios:

```
const baseUrl = 'http://10.0.2.2/lumen-api/public/api/'
const capacitiesUrl = `${baseUrl}maschinen`

      return await Axios.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: capacitiesUrl,
        data: ''
      })
```

After that I got an http-Error. It doesnt work.
I tried to add some permissions to my config.xml-file:

https://medium.com/the-web-tub/electron-on-cordova-29ede5d6d789

and

[How do I add "uses-permissions" tags to AndroidManifest.xml for a Cordova project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042088/how-do-i-add-uses-permissions-tags-to-androidmanifest-xml-for-a-cordova-projec)

My question is now, where should I add some permissions to my android cordova-Application?
I cant find the correct file. Is it only the config.xml-file?

My config.xml-file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.demo.app" 
    version="1.0.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--<widget id="com.vue.example.app" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"> -->
    <name>Hallo Welt</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <!-- this hook will point your config.xml to the DevServer on Serve -->
    <hook type="after_prepare" src="../node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-cordova/serve-config-hook.js" />
    <!-- this hook will point your config.xml to the DevServer on Serve -->
    <hook type="after_prepare" src="../node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-cordova/serve-config-hook.js" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />      
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />                  
        </config-file>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

[Why am I seeing net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED errors after upgrading to Cordova Android 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752716/why-am-i-seeing-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-errors-after-upgrading-to-cordo)

My config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.demo.app" 
    version="1.0.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>VueExampleAppName</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <!-- this hook will point your config.xml to the DevServer on Serve -->
    <hook type="after_prepare" src="../node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-cordova/serve-config-hook.js" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="electron">
        <preference name="ElectronSettingsFilePath" value="res/electron/settings.json" />
        <icon src="res/icon/electron/foreground.png" /> 
    </platform> 
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon background="res/icon/android/background.png" density="ldpi" foreground="res/icon/android/foreground.png" />
        <icon background="res/icon/android/background.png" density="mdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/foreground.png" />
        <icon background="res/icon/android/background.png" density="hdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/foreground.png" />
        <icon background="res/icon/android/background.png" density="xhdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/foreground.png" />
        <icon background="res/icon/android/background.png" density="xxhdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/foreground.png" />
        <icon background="res/icon/android/background.png" density="xxxhdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/foreground.png" />
        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />      
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />  
        </config-file>      
      <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
          <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
      </edit-config>        
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: It's because of the http-request. You have to enable "usesCleartextTraffic". https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic